# How to run commands in Vercel CLI

Tags: python, deployment, fastapi, vercel

I have deployed a fast api project on vercel. The project involves alembic. I need to run "alembic upgrade head" command as I have uploaded all alembic versions.

Please let me know thanks in advance.

I want to run this command "alembic upgrade head" in vercel CLI.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.